# Solspace Freeform Dynamic Recipients Notification Email

Tags: solspace-freeform, notification, dynamic

Using Freeform Next. I have a feeling this is way basic and Im just missing it.

I have a dynamic recipients set up with on a "Select Division" drop down.

Currently the email is returning the email address Im filtering too. I want the option label of the division.

How do I get that?

Basic form is ....

Contact Form Submitted on: {current_time format="%l, %F %j, %Y at %g:%i%a"}

- Name: {field:name:value}
- Email: {field:email:value}
- Phone Number: {field:phone:value}
- Division: {field:division:options}{option:label}{/field:division:options}
- Message: {field:message:value}

Comment: I am having the same issue, were you able to solve this? I would like to display the label of the division the user selected.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up a custom email [notification template](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/docs/email-notifications/#notification-template-database) for the form? You should be able to add `{field:division:label}` and `{field:division:value}` to the body and whatever other variables from the form you want displayed in the notification email. https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/docs/email-notifications/#email-body

Answer (score 0):

I've just found a workaround for this, although it's not very elegant.

On my Dynamic Recipients field, I have 2 options available. Each one has 2 email addresses, which the Notifications will be sent to, upon the customer submitting the form.

```
Option A = email1@domain.com,email2@domain.com
Option B = email3@domain.com,email4@domain.com
```

In my Notifications template, I have then added an if..then..else check to detect which values (as a string) have been submitted, for this Field.

```
<tr>
    <th>{field:fieldname:label}</th>
    <td>{if field:fieldname:value == "email1@domain.com,email2@domain.com"}Option A{if:else}Option B{/if}</td>
</tr>
```

So far, in testing, this has proven successful.
It's a bit clunky because if you change the destination email addresses on the form Field, you have to remember to edit them in the if..then..else statement too.